# Showing Large String in TextView in android

Tags: android, string, textview, format

I need to show a Large text view in android,if the string length is small i want to show the whole text if the String length is high I want to show the texts in first the letters of the String followed by dots and then followed by the last part of the String.

Like if the String is 'Google' i want to show "Google" If the String is 'Google Play Developer Console' I want to show the String something like "Google P...Console" how can I achieve this?

Comment: Use Marquee for your text View.

Comment: @Siddharth Vyas But using marquee it showing the whole text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ellipsize` to abbreviate the text:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:ellipsize="middle"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem

```
android:ellipsize="middle"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string.length() <= 5)
            {
                tvAdd.setText(yourstring);
            }

            else
            {
                tvAdd.setText(yourstring.substring(0, 5) + "..");
            }
```